How to add values from one column in a dataset to another column?
I want to add value of BMI from one dataset to another on ID column. how to do that? the ID column has values repeated number of times in the original dataset. i want for each unique value of ID, its corresponding BMI
for i in range(1, 37): 
    if i in sorted_df_work['ID'].values and i in df_work_2['ID'].values:
        bmi_value = sorted_df_work.loc[sorted_df_work['ID'] == i, 'Body_mass_index'].values[0]
        df_work_2.loc[df_work_2['ID'] == i, 'BMI'] = bmi_value
    else:
        print(f"ID {i} not found in one of the DataFrames.")


ok, so what does you input dataframe look like? What does the desired output look like? Why does your code not do what you want? Does it throw errors? Does it do something different to what you expect?

maybe a simple join can help in this situation?

Yes, a join or a merge would be a much simpler way to do this, but as no example input/output dataframes we can't know for sure

@EmiOB OP wants to "add value of BMI from one dataset to another on ID column", I don't think we have to know the exact schema to suggest a solution

The code is not reading the values of BMI for some reason. The output i get is                       ID   BMI

Sorry, out pit i get is ID 1, BMI 1. Then ID 2, BMI 2 and so on

@Alisha you might want to try the solution shared in the following answer, I've added an extra line of code to keep only the columns ID, BMI and removed duplicates to give your desired solution.

@AhsanMalik no, but looking at the code, OP is clearly a beginner and 'assuming' what their inputs and desired output should look like may only cause further confusion if it's nothing like what they're working with.  Furthermore, it's encouraging poor question writing in stack overflow.  If people want others to take the time to answer their questions, they should provide all the information necessary in the question, not expect people to make assumptions on what the answer may be.

Assuming that your dataset looks like this based on your problem statement:
sorted_df_work = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'Body_mass_index': [22.0, 25.5, 30.1]
})

df_work_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'some_other_column': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
})

You can use the pd.merge function to get your desired output:
merged_df = pd.merge(df_work_2, sorted_df_work, on='ID', how='left')

And rename the column Body_mass_index to BMI:
merged_df.rename(columns={'Body_mass_index': 'BMI'}, inplace=True)

You can select only the 'ID' and 'BMI' columns and drop duplicates like this:
final_result = merged_df[['ID', 'BMI']].drop_duplicates()

Here's the final output:
   ID   BMI
0   1  22.0
3   2  25.5
5   3  30.1

